# Perl use and instead of if

Tags: perl

Is it idiomatic Perl to use a chain of statements linked by `and` operators instead of an `if` with multiple conditions linked by `&&`?

Example: instead of

```
if ($foo && bar() && baz()) {
    do_something();
}
```

use:

```
$foo and bar() and baz() and do_something();
```

Comment: If by "idiomatic Perl" you mean "the sort of thing that used to be very common which led to Perl getting its reputation as a Write Only language"... then yes. Don't write code like that.

Comment: If you are asking about the difference between `and` and `&&`, you should read [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). (TL;DR: Use `and` unless you know what you are doing.) Whether it is idiomatic is likely opinion-based, and off-topic.

Comment: @Wooble By idiomatic Perl I mean nice, readable Perl like `open or die` instead of `if (!open) { die }`.

Comment: You should know that chaining statements using the short-circuiting and operators will stop execution at the first failure. E.g. `if (0 && foo() && bar())` will never run `foo()` or `bar()`. If running each step in your chain is vital, you should extract a return value from each beforehand, e.g. `my $foo = foo(); if ($foo ...)`

Comment: @TLP I'm fully aware how `and` and `&&` work, including their short-circuit nature and their precedence. I'm actually after the opinions. :-)

Comment: @SzG Yes, hence my statement about "opinion-based". You seem to be making a distinction between `and` and `&&` that is not actually there. Perhaps you should just use one or the other to disambiguate.

Comment: There is a difference between `and` and `&&`. The former has much lower precedence, thus allowing to link statements without having to worry about binding stronger than the arguments of the statements.

Comment: In your example it doesn't matter if you use `and` or `&&`, so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490313/perl-use-and-instead-of-if#comment37910430_24490313) is good rule to follow.

Comment: @SzG Yes. Like I said, the simple answer is: Just use `and`. What I mean here is that it seems like you are making a distinction between `and` and `&&` that makes no logical sense in this context. Its like if you were to ask "If eating fruit is good for you, is it better to eat apples at night, or oranges in the morning?"

Comment: As for my opinion on your topic, I would use `if` in any code that I expect another human being to read. The reason? It is more explicit. No one is likely to thank you for being too vague when programming.

Comment: I don't believe you can ever go wrong with an if statement, if for no other reason, keeping maintainable code. I believe you can even get too clever using the conditional operator (? :). I use those for small tests, I want embedded in a statement. Many years ago, when I passed firmware off to DEC's support division, I wasn't appreciated for being cleaver, but instead for leaving code someone could understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read *Perl Best Practices* by Damian Conway. Mr. Conway has struggled with a lot of these issues and put his findings in this book.

It comes down to what the user expects. When you chain the operations, it might be easy to miss that the last item is something you execute and not merely another boolean statement

```
$foo and bar and baz() and do_something();
```

By making it a true `if` statement, it's much easier to see that you have a condition, and if that condition is *true*, you're executing the subroutine `do_something`.

I prefer the use of `and` instead of `&&`:

```
if ($foo and bar() and baz()) {
    do_something();
}
```

This makes it easy to see that you have three conditions and if they're met, you're running something. I like `and` because it's easier to read which makes it a wee bit faster to comprehend, and because it has a *lower* precedence than `&&` and seems to work better in certain places:

```
open my $file, "<", $foo or die qq(Can't open "$foo" for reading);
```

works while:

```
open my $file "<", $foo || die qq(Can't open "$foo" for reading);
```

Doesn't unless you put parentheses around the `open` statement:

```
open ( my $file "<", $foo ) || die qq(Can't open "$foo" for reading);
```

Some people say you can use the postfix `if`, but Conway is doesn't recommend it:

```
do_something() if $foo and bar() and baz();
```

According to Conway, it's easy to miss to miss the conditional. He recommends to use this when the command is short, and it's a way of getting out of exceptions:

```
while ( my $foo = < $bar_fh > ) {
    next if $foo eq $bar;
    ...
}
```

Is preferred over this:

```
while ( my $foo = < $bar_fh > ) {
    if ($foo eq $bar) {
        next;
    }
    ...
}
```

Conway says that the `next` statement is short, and it's handling an exception. In other words, you're doing a loop unless you find when `$foo` is equal to `bar`. In the second, you lose that flow.

Again, if you have these types of questions (and these are good questions. I wish more people took an interest in better coding structure and readability), read *Perl Best Practices*.

Comment: Re "This makes it easy to see that you have three conditions", **Harder** to see. It's easier to pick up symbols in a see of words than specific words in a see of words. It's harder to parse `dfs sadfs and dfsaf and fdsfs asd and asdsa` than it is `dfs sadfs && dfsaf && fdsfs asd && asdsa`. That's the reason operators are normally symbols.

Comment: "This makes it easy to see that you have three conditions" was referring using the `if` statement rather than chaining. I like the `and` & `or` because they do what I usually intend to do. Conway mentions this, but then recommends `&&` and `||` because they "_don't seem to invoke the same levels of fear, uncertainty, or doubt_" Uncertainty? Doubt? How about staring at `if ( $done || $count >= $max )` for hours and wondering why it's not working? `if ( $done or $count >= $max ) ` works. If you want me to stop using unnecessary parentheses, I'm using `and` and `or`, thank you.

Comment: huh? `if ( $done or $count >= $max )` works, so does `if ( $done || $count >= $max )`. The idiom is using `or` for flow control (if it's followed by `next`, `return`, etc), and `||` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to

```
if ($foo && bar() && baz()) {
    do_something();
}
```

it could be used

```
do_something() if $foo && bar() && baz();
```

which preserves separation of condition from desired action and brings simplicity like in `$x && $y && $z`.

Answer (score 0):

My question went more for opinions rather than exact answers, triggering a lot of comments.

Just to summarize them, the commenters found `if ($foo && bar() && baz) { do() }` a bit easier on my fellow humand beings than the flat chain `$foo and bar() and baz() and do();`

Comment: It's a micro-optimization, but `$foo and do()` or `do() if $foo` might be slightly preferred over `if ($foo) { do() }` in a "hot" code path. Curlies mean lexical scope; lexical scopes require a set-up operation and a tear-down operation.